# Authenticating to an API using Python3 with a consumer key and consumer secret

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to login to an API to retrieve an access token using a consumer secret and key. Following several threads on stackoverflow, I've gotten this far:

```
    consumer = "<myconsumerkey>:<myconsumersecret>"
    b64val = base64.b64encode(consumer.encode()).decode()

    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic %s" % b64val, "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencode'}

    response = requests.post('https://mysite/token', headers=headers, verify=False)
```

This always throws a 415 error. I've read the requests api documentation so many times I'm going crazy where is my malfunction here?

Comment: What type of authentication is supported by api?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but adding

`data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}`

to the post worked. The code is:

```
    def login():
    consumer = consumer_key + ":" + consumer_secret
    b64val = base64.b64encode(consumer.encode()).decode()
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic %s" % b64val}
    data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
    response = requests.post('https://mywebsite:8243/token', headers=headers, data=data)
```